# How to fix "Incompatible types.Required: BroadcastReceiver. found: BroadcastReceiver"?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making a jar for use in Unity. Now I'm getting this error when trying to link the broadcastreceiver.

I've tried the given solutions, but they don't work, tried googling around a bit but to no avail, nothing mentions similar required/found.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTrym.png

```java
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        }
    }
};

public void TurnOnBluetooth(){
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); //Init bluetoothadapter

}
public void enableDisableBT(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
    }
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBTIntent);
        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
    }
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        IntentFilter BTIntent = new Intent tFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see only code in the post but no error message text. Could you fix that?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski added an imgur link

Comment: Don't display errors as images.  Images cannot be searched so this post can't help others searching for the same error.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the error is literally in the title

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java expert, but `BroadcastReceiver` is an abstract class ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)) so you cannot create an instance of this class. Maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Question, because I found the fix.

apperently this weird error turns up when you haven't imported.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
```

Paste this above your code and it should be good.